# Finding value of supply voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have the question "For the circuit shown"

[image]

Find the value of the supply voltage V.

I know that the equation for voltage is V = IR.

However, I am not sure what the values for I and R should be ?

Comment: Use I2 and R2 to calculate Vs, use Vs to calculate the other currents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are in parallel, they all have the same voltage across them.

So the V would be 3*20 = 60V
This voltage is the same for the other 2 resistors.  So I1 would be 60/10 = 6A
I3 would be 60/60 = 1A

Comment: So then to work out voltage v, would you do the total current multiplied by the total resistance ? Would that be the final answer for V ? (:

Comment: @DanKhan: You only need the voltage across R2 - the other two branches are in parallel with R2, so must have the same voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Hint - ignore R1 and R3 to find V. Pretend they are not there. Now can you see the simplicity of the basic problem?

It is a bit of a trick question in that there is too  much irrelevant information contained. Focus on what you know and ignore the superfluous visual noise.

Once you have V, the unknown currents are easy to calculate.

Comment: So V = 3 x 20 ? (:

Comment: It can't be anything else!